# Asking for a raise after 7 months

Tags: software-industry, salary, raise

I've joined a company and, after about four months, I have started to perceive my job to be *shifting* to something different from the one I applied for.

For example, I have started *managing people*, which is something that I wasn't expected to do in the beginning. My "informal" title (which is shared to outside customers) has also shifted to something else, which on Glassdoor is associated to salaries which are *twice as much as mine*.

I'm in this job since 7 months. **Should I ask for a >25% raise now?** Or is it considered unprofessional and too large of a step, considering that not even a whole year has passed?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Because it's too soon, or because it's an exaggeratedly high amount? Or both?

Comment: Don't listen to Joe. Ask for it now. It doesn't mean that you're going to get it. But you should still ask. At the very minimum, it plants the seed.

Comment: I'm in agreement with Joe S. I think it's too soon and too much. You haven't even been there a year yet. Keep doing what you're doing and develop and document your thoughts on what you think an acceptable raise should be and why after you pass the 1 year mark. Present them at that time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it 'too soon' to ask for a high raise?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177188/when-is-it-too-soon-to-ask-for-a-high-raise)

Comment: Was the original salary vs original JD/title on the low side, or was there any element of an informal trial period?

Comment: What does "managing people" mean in your case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's up to you.

If you feel you could get the raise, do it. Have your reasoning ready to explain.

I was in a consulting role once at an org where each person was doing the same work, on my team, and were billing the clients the same rate. I was being paid roughly 30% of what the others on the team were, as I was less experienced at the time i was hired (but still fully proficient).

6-7 months in, I had demonstrated I was able to do the same work as my peers, and had even innovated and built out ways to automated much of the work we were doing, making the entire team more productive and improving the number of hours we were billing out for.

I asked for a 50% raise, to a point where I'd still be behind the other team members who had more experience, but would be at a point that was much more reasonable and less likely to get me poached off somewhere else. My manager wasn't able to make the decision (usually has to be cleared by higher ups), but I received a phone call later that day saying it had been approved and they were very enthusiastic about how i'd been doing etc.

So really, it depends. if you have the ability to back it up, you should ask. Especially if you were being underpaid before - Basing pay on %'s from prior pay only continues a low pay situation, it doesn't take into account what you're worth.

Side note - The position I was in when this happened, I had started out 50% higher than the job I was at prior to it, where i'd asked for small raises several times and been denied and gaslit about why I wouldn't get it. But when I had the offer for this new place, all of a sudden, 30 seconds later they were offering to match it and were saying they'd been eyeing me for a supervisor role...

If it's very important, the last resort is to get an offer somewhere else and negotiate as a counter offer to stay at the company... but it may be better off to find another gig anyways. The saying is, if you want more money, you have to job hop.

To answer your other question though - **asking for a raise after 6 months is not unprofessional.** It's only unprofessional if it's for childish or invalid reasons...

By this I mean, your reasons for the raise can't be "I found out Scott is making 100k, we should be getting paid the same", and also shouldn't be "Target pays people $15/hr just for showing up." It should be focused on the value you provide to the business, perhaps the change in your workload and responsibilities (For example maybe that they're shouldering management of other employees onto you, and you hadn't been aware of that / signed up for that when you took the job, now it's a different job than it was before)

Comment: "Target pays people $15/hr just for showing up" totally is a valid reason to ask for a raise if you'd be willing to quit your job to go work for Target for $15 an hour. That's part of how the market helps determine wages, after all.

Comment: @nick012000 yes but no manager is going to be receptive to that for why you should get a raise here - they're going to say... and did you get an offer to work at target? Is this a request for a raise or are we talking about retaining a leaving employee? if that's true maybe you should go there etc etc. it may make them defensive / combative